# How to move an entry from the "show more options" to the default panel on the Windows 11 right-click context menu?

Tags: windows-11

I have installed various apps on Windows 11, which have added their entries on the right-click context menu. However, some are displayed in the default list (eg. WinRAR, PowerRename from PowerToys), most of them are displayed in the "show more options" list(eg. Git Bash).

How can I customize the right-click context menu, to choose which app to be displayed in the default list, which app to be displayed in the "show more options" list?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, do you want to keep that split? If not, you can disable it: https://www.makeuseof.com/remove-show-more-options-context-menu-windows-11/ Otherwise, you'll have to look where the current menu items are in registry, if the new menu even uses that.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'd like to keep that split. I tried to explore the registry but failed to understand how to control appearance in the default view

Comment: I love the new "Show more options" feature except I consider the feature very broken in that the user does not get to decide which entries go on the primary context menu and which entries go on the "Show more options" menu. It is very frustrating that because the feature is not intuitively customizable, all the google search results are regarding disabling the feature but there is no easy way to find out how to customize the feature.